# Select an Item from List in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am making an api call using PowerShell. I get 3 outputs as results from the call.

```
ID : 1
Name :Abc
Location : London
```

I want to pass the ID to a new variable. how can i achieve this in powershell.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the `.` member access operator:

```
$ID = (Call-ThatReturnsObject).ID
```

Or `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
$ID = Call-ThatReturnsObject |Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID
```

Or `ForEach-Object`:

```
$ID = Call-ThatReturnsObject |ForEach-Object -MemberName ID
# or 
$ID = Call-ThatReturnsObject |ForEach-Object { $_.ID }
```